# Does the ssis foreach loop container would throw error if the input directory is not present?

Tags: ssis

I tried with a foreach loop container. I would like to know what happens if the input directory is not present. Would throw error if the input directory is not present?

Comment: Did you try testing this? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there will be an error.
Probably already at validation.

It's quick to try, just do it :)